# Toggle List View(UITableView) and Grid View(UICollectionView) on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uibarbuttonitem

I want to perform an action on UIBarButtonItem which, when clicked, toggles between List View(UITableView) and Grid View(CollectionView)

I have created different view controllers for List View and Grid View.

Initially, the List View should be visible and on UIBarButtonItem click, I want to make the Collection View visible with clean animation.

Comment: I don't see an actual question here.  What part of this are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ViewController's view has TableView and CollectionView both in it. Initially, while designing, one is kept hidden and is unhidden in the code as done below:

```
- (IBAction)btnGrid:(id)sender
{
    if(x == 0)
    {
        grid.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"List.png"];
        myTableView.hidden = TRUE;
        myCollectionView.hidden = FALSE;
        x=1;
    }
    else
    {
        grid.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Grid.png"];
        myTableView.hidden = FALSE;
        myCollectionView.hidden = TRUE;
        x=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the visible view (table/grid) as/to the contentview of the parent/super controller/view. The exchange on button toggle can be done via view animations.